# Microsoft Bot Framework - how to send responses from a 3rd party API

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework

Using Microsoft Bot Framework, how can proxy an API between incoming and outgoing bot messages?

I've replaced:

```
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());
```

with my own implementation that takes `req.body.text` and sends it to a separate endpoint.

How can I send that endpoints response back to the chat?

```
server.post('/api/messages', (req, res, next) => {
  request.post('endpoint', {
    json: {"text": req.body.text},
  }, (error, response, body) => {
    // how to send body as an outgoing chat message?
  })
})
```

Update:

To point out why Ezequiel Jadib's answer won't work, I've added the complete code.
`req` is not defined within the bot's callback function.

```
const restify = require('restify')
const builder = require('botbuilder')
const request = require('request')

// Setup Restify Server
const server = restify.createServer()
server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser())
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
   console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url) 
})

// Create chat connector for communicating with the Bot Framework Service
const connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
})

server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen())

const bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
  request.post('endpoint', {
    json: {"text": req.body.text}
  }, (error, response, body) => {
    session.send(body)
  })
})
```

Comment: Use session.message.text or session.message instead of req.body.text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,  I think you should go through the [documentation for Node.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-quickstart) as this question seems to be related to the foundations of the SDK.

Then, I think that you are calling to your endpoint in the wrong place. Instead of doing it on the post, you should do it in the function of the UniversalBot that is basically where the user messages will be received.

You can try something like:

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
    request.post('endpoint', {
      json: {"text": session.message.text},
    }, (error, response, body) => {
        session.send("You said: %s", "your endpoint response");
   })
});
```

Comment: Again, this does not answer the question since the request needs to be fired once a user has sent a message.  We need to register `server.post` somewhere outside of `new builder.UniversalBot...` and be able to send messages containing contents of the request.

Comment: Is happening there, "function (session)": is basically where you will receive the message sent by the user. In fact, if you do session.send("You said: %s", session.message.text); you will be echoing the user message.

Comment: I've added more code to demonstrate why I believe your solution won't work.  This is the essence of my question.

Comment: Well I just copied/pasted your code, you should use session.message.text or session.message assuming that you wanted to pass the activity or the user text to your endpoint. I updated the code

Comment: That was the missing piece for me.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept messages using the middleware functionality of the Bot Builder Node.js SDK.

From the article [Develop with Node.js > Messages > Intercept Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-intercept-messages):

> The middleware functionality in the Bot Builder SDK enables your bot to intercept all messages that are exchanged between user and bot. For each message that is intercepted, you may choose to do things such as save the message to a data store that you specify, which creates a conversation log, or inspect the message in some way and take whatever action your code specifies.

You can define the middleware function that handles the intercepted message by configuring the `bot.use()` method.

Example:

```
bot.use({
    botbuilder: function (session, next) {
        // this function handles incoming messages sent to your bot
        next();
    },
    send: function (event, next) {
        // this function handles outgoing messages to your user(s)
        next();
    }
});
```

For reference, you can find a working example bot that demonstrates the middleware functionality here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/capability-middlewareLogging